# Facebook add thumbnail when sharing your site

Tags: facebook, thumbnails, addition, facebook-sharer

How can I add a thumbnail when using the facebook.com/sharer.php?u=mysite.com?
I've added this to the header: `<link rel="image_src" href="http://mysite.com/image.jpg"/>`

But:
1. It's not working (yet).
2. It's not valid XHTML.

Is there anyother way or am I doing something wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, image dimensions matter. It must be at least 50x50 pixels, and images must be up to three times as wide as they are tall.

Second, you can use a meta tag to specify the page image, e.g.
`<meta property="og:image" content="http://mysite.com/image.jpg"/>`

Also notice that Facebook caches pages, so if you want to be sure how Facebook handles your latest version, use their [URL Linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/).

See information for example [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like) and [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph) and [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share).

Comment: Thank you Daphna. og:image has not worked for me so far though, but I'll give it a try using the tools you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook will get any image on the page, even hidden ones. For example:

```
<img rel="Facebook image" src="http://mysite.com/image.jpg" />
```

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks. Still doesn't fix the invalid XHTML code, but it's good to know.

Answer (score 0):

I've made this work by adding a display:none on any image that you want to include as a thumbnail image, facebook doesn't care what's not displayed, it only looks for  tags and uses those as thumbnail options.

This works for when you want the user to select a specific image or any image on the page.  Adding the line to the  makes the share button only use that one specific image.